# Can't get reloadData to update table before orientation change when tableViewController inside of navigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, orientation

I have a tableViewController that originally was the main view controller on the screen. When this was the case, I used the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration method to call reloadData to make my table reload its contents. This worked as expected in that upon an orientation change, the table would have its contents reloaded.

Later on, I needed to place the tableViewController into a navigationController. Once this was done, the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration method while still being called, is not properly refreshing the table contents.

My guess is that by placing the tableViewController into the navigationController, this has affected the order that rotation events are sent and when the reloadData method is called, it is too early in the tableView's lifecycle and the change happens before the rotation. I have insured that the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation:duration method is being called with some log statements. Also, just to see what would happen, I implemented the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation method where I placed the reloadData statement and this does properly reload the table contents. However, this happens after the rotation animation, and then redraws the table which creates a noticeable UI shift.

Has anyone else seen this behavior before or know how to fix it?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check out the other view rotation methods. See "Responding to View Rotation Events" in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Perhaps one of these two?

```
- didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
- willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

Comment: It appears that willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration: fires at the proper time and solves my problem. Thanks.